# Параллельное наполнение медленнее последовательного

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность

Написал <s>говнокод</s> небольшую программку, которая по идеи должна наглядно иллюстрировать разницу между последовательной и параллельной работой. На форме есть несколько `ProgressBar`-ов, которые в первом случае заполняются последовательно (один за другим в одном потоке), а во втором - каждый в своем потоке. Ожидалось, что во втором случае процесс заполнения всех `ProgressBar`-ов произойдет быстрее, на деле же - в два раза медленнее. Что я делаю неправильно?

Код:

```
   //Последовательно..
    private void LoadsConsistently()
    {
        foreach (ProgressBar PB in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Minimum = 0));
            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Maximum = 100000));
            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Step = 1));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.PerformStep()));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    // Паралельно, каждый в своем потоке
    private void LoadsParallel() 
    {
    foreach(ProgressBar PB in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {

            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Minimum = 0));
            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Maximum = 100000));
            PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.Step = 1));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                PB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => PB.PerformStep()));
            }
        timer1.Stop();
        }
        ).Start();
    }
    }
```

Ссыль: http://dropmefiles.com/fHy41

Comment: Могу предложить отмазку, что на постоянное переключение контекста требуется дополнительное времени.

Comment: @Alex78191 Всмысле между GUI и паралельным потоком ?

Comment: Переключение контекстов потоков на процессоре.

Comment: Это же не параллельная работа с задачами, которые не полностью процессор нагружают, параллельное скачивание файлов зависит не от процессора, а от скорости интернета.

Comment: Вообще у меня давно при использовании BeginInvoke в новом потоке форма не обновлялась и приходилось ждать завершения метода onClick.

Comment: @Alex78191 скорость интернета тут причем?

Comment: это для примера использовал

Comment: Вы неправильно время считаете `date.AddMilliseconds(1);` по умолчанию интервал равен 100 мс. Но это только на размерность влияет.

Comment: Последовательно вышло 6,8 с, параллельно 4,6 с.

Comment: Для вычисления времени выполнения лучше использовать [stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: `Последовательно вышло 6,8 с, параллельно 4,6 с` не может быть, у меня 4.6 паралельно и 0.9 последовательно

Comment: Длительность выводится только в конце. `label1.BeginInvoke` не работает

Comment: @Alex78191да, вы правы. это тоже странно

Comment: последовательно https://i.imgur.com/y0KDBUG.png параллельно https://i.imgur.com/aSm945d.png

Comment: «invok'и  не обязательны, нужно лишь св-во формы CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls поставить в false и работать с контролами как с потока gui.»

Comment: @Alex78191 `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` это свойство в wpf, в формах его нет

Comment: Неправда, это как раз из форм. в WPF нет https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) выполняется асинхронно. То есть ваш код создаёт очередь сообщений на обновление контролов и прекращает свою работу. Это время и замеряется. А очередь ещё долго потом выполняется.

Comment: Настройку паарметров ProgressBar лучше вынести за цикл.

Comment: `Неправда, это как раз из форм` ваша правда, не заметил сразу

Comment: `выполняется асинхронно` при замене на `Invoke` результат тот же. видимо я совершенно неправильно  создаю потоки

Comment: Поле замены `BeginInvoke` на `Invoke` Длительность стала отображаться динамически, а не в конце. Графики стали плавно заполняться.

Comment: @Alex78191 на счет длительности - правда, стала отражаться динамически, но все равно параллельное заполнение идет гораздо медленнее

Comment: @Сергей вам уже сказали почему разницы быть не должно. У меня наоборот паралл быстрее.

Comment: @Alex78191 да, то и странно: не должно а она есть

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сравнение скорости движения поездов методом бега без штанов по крыше электрички с термометром в руках.

Работать с контролами можно только в гуёвом потоке. Так как это единственное, что вы делаете, то вы замеряете скорость служебного кода, не относящегося к прямому назначению программы: переключение миежду потоками, отрисовка контролов, проброска виндовых сообщений, генерация мусора и прочее.

Многопоточности в вашем коде нет, параллельности нет. Просто во втором случае вы зачем-то прыгаете между гуёвым потоком и левым потоком. Если вы наблюдаете существенную разницу, то вы делаете что-то не так. В данном случае — 100 000 раз обновляете положение прогресс-бара, хотя достаточно это делать в 1000 раз меньше. Если вы будете обновлять 100 раз, то разницы будет примерно ноль, если ваш метод `PerformStep` хоть что-то делает.

Параллельность начнётся, когда ваш `PerformStep` будет выполняться частями в разных потоках.

Comment: `Многопоточности в вашем коде нет, параллельности нет.`  а как же `new System.Threading.Thread` ?

Comment: @Сергей Параллельность — это когда *работа* выполняется *параллельно*. У вас работа (`PerformStep`) выполняется строго последовательно: ни в один момент времени не могут выполняться два `PerformStep` одновременно.

Comment: т.е. проблема именно в `PerformStep` ?

Comment: работать с контролами параллельно нельзя ?

Comment: @Сергей Проблема во всём. Здесь нет ни одной правильной строчки кода. Если хотите многопоточность, то сначала определитесь, чего вы хотите с её помощью достичь. Если хотите изучить многопоточность, то начинайте не с WinFiorms, которые всё только усложняют. Все контролы существуют в одном потоке, и работать с ними можно только через него. Распараллеливать нечего.

Comment: @Squidward как будто в WPF нет `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @Alex78191 Зачем вообще гуй при изучении многопоточности?

Comment: `Все контролы существуют в одном потоке. Распараллеливать нечего`   об этом я не подумал, спасибо за пояснение

Comment: `Зачем вообще гуй при изучении многопоточности?`  планировалось для наглядности- как лучше а получилось ....

Comment: Ну знать как выполнять действия в отдельном потоке без замораживания потока GUI и динамически отображать результат надо.

Comment: @Alex78191 Ну в общем от цели надо исходить, а не от желания добавить многопоточности. Пока что обе версии кода потенциально будут подвешивать гуй, правда с несколько разными спецэффектами.